# Upgrading from OwnCloud 8.2.3 to OwnCloud 9.0.1 results in css and js being served as text/html

Tags: .htaccess, mime-types, owncloud

I have been using owncloud for quite a while now on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS headless server.

A couple days ago I tried to upgrade to OwnCloud 9.0.1 and upon logging in for the first time after the upgrade I was presented with non styled layout.

If I look in the browser console I see many errors about incorrect mime types:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.domain.at/cloud/core/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=a283428d5f34c45e26387d89361a95ba' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
www.domain.at/:1 
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.domain.at/cloud/core/vendor/jquery-migrate/jquery-migrate.min.js?v=a283428d5f34c45e26387d89361a95ba' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
www.domain.at/:1 
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.domain.at/cloud/core/vendor/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.custom.js?v=a283428d5f34c45e26387d89361a95ba' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
www.domain.at/:1 
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.domain.at/cloud/core/vendor/underscore/underscore.js?v=a283428d5f34c45e26387d89361a95ba' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
www.domain.at/:1 
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.domain.at/cloud/core/vendor/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js?v=a283428d5f34c45e26387d89361a95ba' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
www.domain.at/:1 
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.domain.at/cloud/core/vendor/handlebars/handlebars.js?v=a283428d5f34c45e26387d89361a95ba' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
www.domain.at/:1 
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.domain.at/cloud/core/vendor/blueimp-md5/js/md5.js?v=a283428d5f34c45e26387d89361a95ba' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
www.domain.at/:1 
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.domain.at/cloud/core/vendor/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js?v=a283428d5f34c45e26387d89361a95ba' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
www.domain.at/:1 
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.domain.at/cloud/core/vendor/backbone/backbone.js?v=a283428d5f34c45e26387d89361a95ba' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
www.domain.at/:1 
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.domain.at/cloud/core/vendor/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js?v=a283428d5f34c45e26387d89361a95ba' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
www.domain.at/:1 
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.domain.at/cloud/core/vendor/davclient.js/lib/client.js?v=a283428d5f34c45e26387d89361a95ba' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
www.domain.at/:1 
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.domain.at/cloud/core/js/placeholders.js?v=a283428d5f34c45e26387d89361a95ba' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I have checked to ensure that the mime types module is enabled.

I have tried adding:

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
```

To the `.htaccess` file that is in my owncloud root directory but that has not helped.

I also tried adding it to the `.htaccess` file that is in the root web folder and that too has had no effect.

Is there something I am missing? What else should I check?

I am asking here because owncloud devs were of the opinion that this is likely due to server configuration issue.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me to.

I just copied my owncloud 8.2.x `.htaccess` back and that seems to have fixed it.

I don't care enough to go find the exact cause, everything is working, but it does seem like ownclouds problem that they need to either find the cause if it is a apache/nginx/ubuntu/whatever setup issue, or just fix it, seeing as the old `.htaccess` works.

Owncloud now complains that the `.htaccess` file fails integrity checks, but that's not an issue for me.

If you have found a actual solution please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up fixing the issue for me was to follow the [manual upgrade instructions](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/maintenance/manual_upgrade.html) word for word. Once I did that all worked without problems or errors.